# Typescript: Types are removed for a generic interface/function

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript2.0

I seem to be an idiot, this is in VSCode using typescript.

When I define an interface, and then attempt to use that interface in a function the intellisense seems to be removed.  Since it's a little hard to explain, I added a picture to describe it.
In the first picture, you can see that I am able to get intellisense for the send function.
In the second (when I actually attempt to use it), you can see that both intellisense and type information has been removed.  How do I resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Highly recommend different emitters for different events : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/typed-event.html

Comment: File an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues This should be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running into this known TypeScript issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14344

This is a bug as of TypeScript 2.5. The type checking should all work properly, we just don't provide the correct suggestions in this case